# IPhone Weather App

Tags: iphone, ios4, weather

I want to make a weather forecasting app. which api should i use to predict today, tomorrow, and day after tomorrow's weather.
i heard people saying yahoo api cannot be used and apple can reject your app?

is there any good tutorial available then please post a link too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't know about the weather API, but I am using the Yahoo Maps API in an app that is in the app store.

Answer (score 1):

You can refer these links, may be they can be useful.

http://www.jaymatter.com/2008/09/23/google-weather-api/

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305127/free-weather-api

Thanks